# Flash inside a draggable div

Tags: javascript, flash, html

I have a flash video player sitting inside a div container. That is made draggable using javascript. I dont want it to be sensitive to dragging when the mouse is on the flash part. It should be draggable only when mouse is on the remaining div container. The expected behavior happens in Linux. However, in windows cursor on mouse makes it draggable as well. How can I avoid that. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you even have control over this behaviour. If there is no immediate solution, an alternative would be to create a drag-handle for the div container. So you move the entire div by dragging the handle, and only the handle is sensitive to the drag-action (just like with most Windows forms, you can move an entire window by dragging its title bar).

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your mouse enters the flash rectangle, it can only control the flash content and you lose all control over the html, javascript or not.

I imagine this to work like a paddling pool on wheels. Try to push the paddling pool around by moving the water, and all you end up with is wet hands.

It may be possible to add a 'handle' to the outside of the flash content, which will then move the flash content around when dragged.

[alt text http://cnb-host3.clickandbuild.com/cnb/shop/powerranger?imageID=1218&op=imgLib-viewImage](http://cnb-host3.clickandbuild.com/cnb/shop/powerranger?imageID=1218&op=imgLib-viewImage)